# Express return undefined in validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, validation

I have a problem with validation, below is my code:

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var hello_controller = require('../api/controllers/helloController');
var { validationRules, validator } = require("../validate/validator");

router.post('/hello/add', validationRules, validator, hello_controller.addHello );

module.exports = router;
```

controller.js

```
exports.addHello = function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World");
}
```

validator.js

```
module.exports.validationRules= [
    body("title")
        .exists()
        .withMessage("Title is Required")
        .isString()
        .withMessage("Title must be a String")
        .trim(),
    //other rules
]

module.exports.validator = validator;


function validator(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) //undefined CAN SOMEONE TELL ME WHY?
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (errors.isEmpty()) {
    next();
  }
  const extractedErrors = []
  errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }))

  return res.json({
    errors: extractedErrors
  })
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const helloRoutes = require("./routes/routes");

app.use('/api', helloRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`APP running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

on launch my `POST` request, my `req` return me `undefined` instead of object sending via `Postman`, because of this, my `validator` return me all errors from the `validationRules` array, can someone tell me what is wrong here and why my `req` is `undefined`?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a middleware in order to deserialize the request body. Assuming you are using JSON as data format, add this in your server.js:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: Thanks!, I accept your answer in few minutes

Comment: Thank you in advance!